# Subset of R^3 and the dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = \{( x_1 , x_2 , x_3 ) \in \mathbb{R}^3 ∣ x_1 − 4x_2 + 2x_3 = 0\}.$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Find vector $\vec{n}$, which satisfies $A = \{ \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3 ∣ \vec{x} ⋅ \vec{n} = 0 \}.$

Im bit stuck with this. My assumption was that they wanted to find $\vec{n}$ to be orthogonal to $\vec{x}$, but it seems that's not the case here?

Comment: $\vec{n}=(1,-4,2)$...

Comment: Have you written down the equations you obtain from the orthogonality?  First of all, $0$ is a trivial solution to this. Second, if $\text{span}(A)\neq \mathbb{R}^3$ then the orthogonal complement is not $0$, and you have a non zero orthogonal vector.

Comment: "orthogonal to all the $\vec x$ belonging to $A$"

Comment: It seems you are more confused about what is being asked then about how to find the answer. I'll try to break it down to the point where we arrive at Ted's comment. The definition of $n$ reads '$n$ is such that $A$ equals exactly the set of elements in $\mathbb{R}^3$ orthogonal to $n$'. This is indeed a bit confusing. It would already be clearer, I guess if they gave the same definition in reverse order: '$n$ is such that the set of elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that are orthogonal to $n$ is exactly the set $A$'. ctd in next comment

Comment: This can be translated further to a pair of two statements: 1) every element of $A$ is orthogonal to $n$ and 2) any element of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is not in A is not orthogonal to $n$. 

Statement 2 seems of the kind that is too fuzzy to get a handle on, but statement 1 is concrete. So the best course of action is to try and find an $n$ that satisfies statement 1 and then check if we get statement 2 for free. Geometrically this seems not so outrageous. If, by some dark magic, the set $A$ happens to be a 2-dimensional plane through the origin then any $n$ satisfying 1 also satisfies 2.

Comment: So we try to focuss on finding an $n$ such that $n$ is orthogonal to all elements in $A$ or, equivalently (as Ted says) such that every $x$ in $A$ is orthogonal to $n$.

Comment: How would this look visually? I might get a better understanding by looking at a plot of this.

Answer (score 0):

A vector $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in $A$ satisfies that 
$$(x_1,x_2,x_3) \cdot (1,-4,2) = x_1 - 4x_2 + 2x_3 = 0$$
which is the same as saying that every vector, $x$, of $A$ is *orthogonal* to $(1,-4,2)$. So, just pick $\vec{n} = (1,-4,2)$.